# Display dialog with 3 results?

Tags: applescript

I have been attempting to build a script that gives you the option of 3 different action via a display dialog box, but when I test them out only the first option works. Is there a work-around for this as this is the center point of my program. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

```
set myQuery to display dialog "selection?" buttons {"choice 1", "choice 2", "choice 3"}
if the button returned of myQuery is "choice 1" then do script
if the button returned of myQuery is "choice 2" then do script
if the button returned of myQuery is "choice 3" then do script
```

In this case only the choice one script works and the other two fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track.  This should work for you

```
set myQuery to display dialog "selection?" buttons {"choice 1", "choice 2", "choice 3"}
if button returned of myQuery is "choice 1" then
    say "you selected choice one" --replace this line with what ever you want
end if
if button returned of myQuery is "choice 2" then
    say "you selected choice two" --replace this line with what ever you want
end if
if button returned of myQuery is "choice 3" then
    say "you selected choice three" --replace this line with what ever you want
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is anoying realising i was so close but now i have the answer. Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: Believe me I understand the frustration.  I am new to AppleScript and the only solution I can come up with is read read read and practice practice practice. It's kind of fun though... The whole process.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of redundancy in your code and three separate `if` clauses are not efficient.

```
set {button returned:myQuery} to display dialog "selection?" buttons {"choice 1", "choice 2", "choice 3"}
if myQuery is "choice 1" then
    say "choice one"
else if myQuery is "choice 2" then
    say "choice two"
else
    say "choice three"
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I'm still learning but I do appreciate you pointing it out.